In a leaf, how does the water get out of the xylem?
In every textbooks, one can read that the xylem transports water and nutriments up to the leaves while the phloem transports the sap down to each parts of the tree, and that both the xylem and phloem are structurally different. The mental image being two different sets of pipes. My question is about their structure at both end, in the roots and in the leaves?
From what I see on leaf cross section pictures, unlike the arteries and veins in the lungs, the xylem and phloem remain separate structures in leaves.

And the vessels seem to form closed loops:

The mental model I have for the xylem is (the same for the phloem with a down arrow):


Question 1

How and where does the water get out of the xylem? Are the walls of the xylem becoming leaky in the leaves?

Question 2

If the sugar rich sap flows down the phloem, it needs to exit somewhere. What happens to the sap once it has reached the roots? Transpiration is the process that generates the outflow of water in the leaves, but what is the equivalent process in the roots for the sap?


Okay, for your second question, consider the force that creates the potential difference as follows: The sugar sap that runs along the phloem contains far more sucrose than the root cell. Although sucrose molecules are supplied to root cells, and one may expect the root cells to have a higher concentration of sucrose over time, they are instead transformed into starch, therefore the concentration of sucrose in root cells stays low in comparison to the phloem. This could lead to a difference in the net transfer of sucrose from leaves to roots, just like transpiration in leaves, which is responsible for water transit from root to leaf. The low sucrose concentration in root cells and the high number of sucrose in leaves cause sucrose to be transferred from leaf to root. The sucrose that has arrived is transported to the root cells via facilitated diffusion and converted to starch.
To summarize: starch is insoluble and therefore it's osmotic effect in roots is small. In that case sucrose from high concentration(from leaves) to low concentration(root cells) is feasible.
https://bio.libretexts.org/Courses/Saint_Mary's_College_Notre_Dame_IN/Foundations_of_Form_and_Function/07%3A_Transport_and_Gas_Exchange/7.05%3A_Phloem_Transport

The xylem is composed of hydrophilic fibers like cellulose and lignin, so it is "water-conductive".
To understand water movement in plants, it's important to differentiate between apoplastic and symplastic pathways. Apoplastic water moves through the cell walls and intercellular spaces, providing a source of extracellular water. Symplastic water, on the other hand, is transported directly from cell to cell through plasmodesmata.
In short, there's no hydrophobic separation between xylem and phloem other than the cell membrane.

If the xylem is water conductive, then how does water manage to get to the leaves without being lost between the roots and the canopy?

It may be worth noting in the answer that the pores are able to be dilated and constricted. The mechanism of that might be the subject of another question.

Cork and wax prevent evaporation from leaves and steams. @Jiminy The pores you referring to are the stomata? If so I didn't mentioned because they are more related to gas exchange and water loss to the environment, and not to symplastic-apopplastic water movements.

No, I meant the plasmodesmata. I suspected Shaktyai's concern was that the leakage due to gravity and "first in  the queue" of the lower tissues might prevent the canopy getting any water. It's regulated by the formation of (temporary) carbohydrate plaques that accrete around the openings, narrowing  and attenuating the flow. @heracho
